# How do I avoid the error during filing for an utility provisional application?

Tags: provisional-application, utility-patent

Upon clicking on filing for a utility provisional application I get two options and a warning that I am signing in as a guest user even though I am logged in.
If i sign in again it doesn't make any difference, if I continue the result is 401 error.
Any advice?

Comment: So you have a Customer Number with the USPTO?

Comment: I think you need to follow up with the USPTO.

Comment: What happens if you click on the filing for new utility provisional application as a guest? There is no 401 error?

Comment: I believe that your log in credentials aren't being accepted. Try to contact the USPTO to fix that. Also, sometimes trying a different browser like Chrome or Firefox can help along with resetting the browser's cache file.